# Polynomial tending to infinity

Tags: polynomials, roots

Take any polynomial $(x-a_1)(x-a_2)\ldots(x-a_n)$ with roots $a_1, a_2,\ldots,a_n$  where we order them so that $a_{i+1}>a_i$ is increasing so $a_n$ is the biggest root. It doesn't matter whether the polynomial is of odd or even degree or whether there is a minus sign in front of highest power of $x$ since all these cases can be treated similarly. How do you show rigorously that after $x=a_n$ the polynomial is a **strictly** increasing function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is the product of positive and strictly increasing functions.

Alternatively: The derivative of $p$ has degree $n-1$ and at least one root in each interval $(a_i,a_{i+1})$ (Rolle). Hence it has no root besides these, especially it does not change signs beyond $x=a_n$.

Comment: I just realised! facepalm

Comment: For alternative I understand up to Rolle. But not the bit about it not changing sign after $x=a_n$ Please could you elaborate? I also understand why these are only roots btw Edit: I understand

Comment: If a polynomial p(x) changes sign as x goes from a to b,then p has to take the value 0 at least once between a and b.